# Selenium Webdriver failing to close cleanly

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I am trying to run a TestNG suite to test the various different types of accounts on an application. The suite runs with no errors but when quitting, webdriver always fails to close cleanly providing the following stacktrace:

```
    Jul 29, 2015 4:23:41 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@4c2bb6e0
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'PC100740', ip: '10.2.211.148', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:628)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:474)
    at selenium.Log_In_Guest.superTearDown(Log_In_Guest.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:308)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:7056 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:134)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.execute(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver$LazyCommandExecutor.execute(FirefoxDriver.java:392)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:578)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:74)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    ... 36 more
```

The relevant code snippet is:

```
@AfterMethod
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
     driver.close();
     String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
     if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
         Assert.fail(verificationErrorString);
     }
  }

  @AfterSuite
  public void superTearDown() throws Exception {
      try{
          driver.quit();
      }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

I have seen many other topics on this, all around a year old and none providing a solution that solves my problem...

This issue is happening on all test cases I am writing, JUnit and TestNG. I am running these in Eclipse.

This is with Firefox 38.0 (but was also happening with 39)

Comment: which browser and browser version are you using?

Comment: edited with my browser and version (firefox 38)

Comment: try using lower firefox versions (33) or try running HTML Unit Driver once... see if it works.
<br>
`WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();`

Comment: try `driver.quit()` instead

Comment: Remove `driver.close();` use only the `driver.quit();`!

Comment: I agree with Amney, driver.quit() is recommended to use in aftersuite(), comment it out in afterMethod().

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're already closing the driver within your @AfterMethod.

You're essentially trying to close the driver twice.  Also, it is recommended not to use driver.close(), but rather use driver.quit() ALWAYS.

This code snippet should help you out:

```
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        Assert.fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
}

@AfterSuite
public void superTearDown() throws Exception {
    if(driver.getSessionId() != null)
    {
        try{
            driver.quit();
        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your snippet, and am still getting the same "Command failed to close cleanly", but now after every method.  It looks like `driver.quit()` is causing the error

Comment: it may be caused by some code we haven't seen yet then.  That error should really only be getting thrown if the browser is already closed when driver.quit() is called.

Answer (score 0):

Use driver.quit() preferably only in @AfterMethod.
@AfterMethod would kill the driver instance after each test case. You don't need to pile up the driver instance and kill in @AfterSuite (Unless you have any specific reason).